# Electric Shock in Walls and Electrical Equipment

Tags: grounding

I'm getting a shock when I touch walls, electrical equipment like a water cooler, fridge, etc in my home. I have followed [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/246683/146933) procedure as I only have a DMM with me.

The readings I got after checking with DMM are:
L-N: 249.2 V
L-E: 255.5 V
N-E: 14.5 V

As mentioned in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/246683/146933) procedure, theoretically voltage difference between neutral and earth will be zero and considered as proper earthing, but practically it will be 2 to 4 AC volts. Whereas, in my case, I'm getting around 14.5VAC which is significantly high. Hence, I may be getting shock in my home appliances.

Please help me in identifying and rectifying the issue!!

Comment: this makes absolutely no sense without an explanation .... `I'm getting a shock when I touch walls` ......... your post contains almost no information .... there is no way to determine if there is an actual issue

Comment: Is the shock a brief "snap" (static electricity) or a continuous "buzz" (mains leakage)?

Comment: Hi Dave,Its a continuous buzz

Comment: I think this should be taken off hold. Essentially his question is "What are some potential reasons my neutral to earth voltage is so high?" Maybe more relevant for the home improvement stack exchange, but a decent question none the less.

Comment: There is a  ground fault  Fix it.

Comment: Neutral should not on the appliance surface. It is the voltage between you and  earth gnd and the appliance surface that shows a connection problem. They , the plumbing or sink and you should all be near the same potential, regardless of what it is. Find out that difference.

Comment: Can you get a non-contact voltage detector to bear on this? That N-G difference shouldn't be sufficient to cause a serious shock....

Comment: what type of walls? 15v is considered safe even for swimming pool lighting.